# Constructing a special matrix in numpy dynamically

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

So my objective is the following, given the size of the matrix `s`, I am attempting to create a matrix that looks like the following, but for size `sxs`:

```
[1 1 0]
[1 1 1]
[0 1 1]
```

For the size of 4x4, it would look something like the following:

```
[1 1 0 0]
[1 1 1 0]
[0 1 1 1]
[0 0 1 1]
```

Therefore you can observe a pattern: there are `s-1` number of overlapping mini `2x2` ones matrices.

I was thinking of creating a `2x2` ones matrix and then by using a dynamic referencing (for loop?) like `B[:-1,:-1] = ones_matrix`, where `B` is the zeros matrix of size `sxs`. But I am not sure how to incorporate a for loop here, because if we take say a `4x4` matrix, then we would have to reference `B` in three ways like so: `B[:-1,:-1] = ones_matrix, B[1:-1,1:-1] = ones_matrix, B[2:,2:]=ones_matrix`. And I can't figure out a way to do that dynamically for `n`-sized zeros matrix. Is there perhaps another way to do this?

Comment: i think I know how to do it. I can actually use the dynamic referencing

Comment: This is simply a [tridiagonal matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix), might simplify explanations in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Method #1: Instead of a bunch of 2x2 matrices, it might be easier to look at it as three diagonals of 1 and combine those:

```
>>> s = 3
>>> np.diag([1]*s,0) + np.diag([1]*(s-1),-1) + np.diag([1]*(s-1), 1)
array([[1, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 1]])
>>> s = 4
>>> np.diag([1]*s,0) + np.diag([1]*(s-1),-1) + np.diag([1]*(s-1), 1)
array([[1, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 1]])
```

Method #2: (inspired by Divankar's answer), we can think in terms of distance from the centre:

```
>>> s = 4
>>> i,j = np.indices((s,s))
>>> (abs(i-j) <= 1).astype(int)
array([[1, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 1]])
```

Method #3: we could take advantage of `tril` or `triu` and do some arithmetic:

```
>>> m = np.tril(np.ones((s,s)),1)
>>> m * m.T
array([[ 1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.]])
>>> m = np.tril(np.ones((s,s)),2)
>>> m * m.T
array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.]])
```

Comment: Oh, this is great! Thank you

Comment: What if you wanted not an integer value in the diagonals but say the whole matrix! So you have matrix diagonals. Would you go np.diag(A*s,0) ?

Comment: @isquared-KeepitReal: that's a bit of a different question.  You could open a new one with some examples of what you want, though!

Answer (score 1):

Vectorized approach with [`broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) -

```
A = np.arange(s)
out = ((A[:,None] < A+2) & (A[:,None] > A-2)).astype(int)
```

Sample run -

```
In [60]: s = 3
    ...: A = np.arange(s)
    ...: out = ((A[:,None] < A+2) & (A[:,None] > A-2)).astype(int)
    ...: 

In [61]: out
Out[61]: 
array([[1, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 1]])

In [62]: s = 4
    ...: A = np.arange(s)
    ...: out = ((A[:,None] < A+2) & (A[:,None] > A-2)).astype(int)
    ...: 

In [63]: out
Out[63]: 
array([[1, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 1]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use sympy.Matrix also:

```
from sympy import Matrix
Matrix(4, 4, lambda i,j: 1 if (-2<i-j<2) else 0)

Matrix([
[1, 1, 0, 0],
[1, 1, 1, 0],
[0, 1, 1, 1],
[0, 0, 1, 1]])
```

Comment: Thank you, I will check it out