# Matrix with identical diagonals

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

Please refer to the below:

[Constructing a special matrix in numpy dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33523552/constructing-a-special-matrix-in-numpy-dynamically/33523779?noredirect=1#comment54833151_33523779)

Is there a way to now actually create a matrix in a similar fashion, in which the diagonal values are in themselves matrices. For example:

```
[A 0 0 0]
[0 A 0 0]
[0 0 A 0]
[0 0 0 A]
```

Where A is for example:

```
[1 1]
[1 1]
```

and 0 is a similar size matrix, so

```
[0 0]
[0 0]
```

Perhaps, using the method introduced in the answer in the link. i.e. `np.diag(Matrix*s,0)`.

Suppose also I would like to have some other matrix of the same sizes as the ones before, but this matrix would run the diagonals above and below `A` like so:

```
[A B 0 0]
[B A B 0]
[0 B A B]
[0 0 B A]
```

Comment: [`Create block diagonal numpy array from a given numpy array`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33508322/create-block-diagonal-numpy-array-from-a-given-numpy-array) might help? In your case, `n = 4; out = np.kron(np.eye(n), A)`.

Comment: Might do the trick :) thanks. Would that work for the diagonals immediately above or immediately below the A's?

Comment: Edit your question with such a case and explain the expected output please.

Comment: edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I think @Divakar's suggestion is best, with using `numpy.kron` in conjunction with `numpy.eye`.  The key is to use the `np.eye(N, M=N, k)`, where `k` specifies the diagonal of the identity matrix.  Use `k = 0` for the standard identity, but for off-diagonal terms, use `k = +/- 1`. For example:

```
A = np.ones((2,2))
B = 2*A
C = np.kron(np.eye(4), A)
C += np.kron(np.eye(4, k=1), B)
C += np.kron(np.eye(4, k=-1), B)
```

Yields

```
array([[ 1.,  1.,  2.,  2.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  2.,  2.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 2.,  2.,  1.,  1.,  2.,  2.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 2.,  2.,  1.,  1.,  2.,  2.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  2.,  2.,  1.,  1.,  2.,  2.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  2.,  2.,  1.,  1.,  2.,  2.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  2.,  2.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  2.,  2.,  1.,  1.]])
```

Comment: Good use of that "offset" thing, `k`!